# Is it safe to use [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: ... freeWhenDone:NO] with a const byte array as input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have a large binary resource in my code, converted to an array using a bin2c type program.

Previously, we are using `[NSData dataWithBytes:raw length:rawLength]` to read the resource (for example).

This is a very large array (>32KB) and the whole procedure around loading and using this resource is slow at the moment so I am trying to make time savings where I can (no I haven't explicitly profiled the copy vs noCopy at this time).

I am just wondering, since `dataWithBytesNoCopy:` takes a `void*` and not `const void*`, does this mean it is not safe to use this from a constant source (in this case it is compiled into the program executable).

I don't think it is an oversight from the NSData developers since `initWithBytes:` and `dataWithBytes:` both take `const void*` as the parameter - what (if anything) does NSData do to the input data when not const, considering that NSData itself is immutable?

I wonder if perhaps the parameter defined as not `const` for forward compatibility with NSMutableData?

Comment: Think about NS[Mutable]String -- it has similar methods, but will NSString just use your string as-is, or convert it to default internal representation? Likely. I think what Apple said in docs is "dude, i can free it for you, but it is mine now, okay?". It might work now and break tomorrow (unlikely, but how do you know?)

Comment: I think the best course is to refactor my code to avoid using NSData in this case! Or build an NSData "like" class which responds to the correct selectors and internally only uses const access to the underlying memory.

Comment: I am not sure whether you find the solution or not. I face with similar problem. and I fixed it using code at link http://stackoverflow.com/a/26867608/1508868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:…] is mapped to CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy() or similar low-level function, whose documentation describes a little more about how it treats original bytes:

> Discussion
>
> This function creates an immutable CFData object from a buffer of unstructured bytes. Unless the situation warrants otherwise, the created object does not copy the external buffer to internal storage but instead uses the buffer as its backing store. However, you should never count on the object using the external buffer since it could copy the buffer to internal storage or might even dump the buffer altogether and use alternative means for storing the bytes.

In other words, buffer *may* be copied, and you can't rely on "propagation" of changes to original buffer to NSData, but that is not the problem. Original question is still unanswered: whether it would modify original bytes in-place (although the hint may be pretty obvious now).

UPDATE:

If situation permits, you may load NSData only once, and then just copy it in hot loop (copy is cheap, because NSData is immutable and shares contents).

```
static const char *myBytes = "myBytes here...";
static NSData *myData = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:myBytes length:strlen(myBytes)]; // EDIT: still need to copy to be clean
});

for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    NSData *hotLoopData = [myData copy];
    NSData *hotLoopData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:myData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it isn't conclusive. I think it's safest to err on the side of safety (I hate to cast away const unless I have an extremely good reason anyway)

Comment: @WayneUroda btw, can't you just create NSData once (your data is long-living static-const, right?) and then just -[copy] it?

Answer (score 2):

At worst NSData will copy the bytes anyway. The declaration most likely dates back to the old days when the compiler would be confused if it saw two declarations with the same method name but different types.

Comment: NSData won't copy the bytes if I have written dataWithBytesNoCopy... or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that your rep is 1337? ;)

Comment: Some men just want to watch the karma burn.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is getting upvoted, it doesn't really answer the question. Unless you can back up your claim that NSData will copy the bytes?

Comment: @WayneUroda "upvoted, it doesn't really answer the question". Welcome to SO!

Comment: @WayneUroda: This does answer the question — he said that it will not modify the data you pass, because it will copy the bytes anyway in the worst case. And Greg Parker is one of the people who wrote the code you're using when you write Objective-C, so I'm not sure what better source you're looking for to back up his claims.

Comment: I was looking for some sort of explanation or supporting evidence. It's cool, I will err on the side if caution, I hate to cast away const anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`+ (id)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length freeWhenDone:(BOOL)freeWhenDone`

why the type of `bytes` is `void *` not `const void *` ?

Apple Development document tells that "If freeWhenDone is YES, the returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it on deallocation."

Look at how is the `free` function declared.

`void    free(void *);` It take void * as parameter.

That why `bytes` should be `void *` not `const void *`.

**updated for you question in title.**

I think you should not worry about the safety problem, because it seems that the memory used to store binary resource is not the read-only memory.

If the memory isn't marked const by system, you can change it anyway.

`const void *` just means you can't change the memory by the instance, it doesn't mean the memory is read-only.

An example , No crash here.

memory created on stack.

```
int a = 1 ;
const void * pc = (const void *)&a ;
*(char *)(pc) = 'a' ;
```

memory created on heap.

```
void * p = malloc(4) ;
const void * pc = p ;
*(char *)(pc) = 'a' ;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, but can you comment on the title question, that is, is it safe to use a const data source when freeWhenDone is NO?

Comment: @WayneUroda What's the "safe" means.

Comment: Well if NSData attempts to write to that const data it will cause a SIGBUS (since that data is in read-only memory). This is what I mean by safe - is NSData guaranteed to not make any writes to the memory passed in with noCopy.

Comment: @WayneUroda You can have it a try, I am not sure about that. What do you think of read-only memory? If the memory is on stack or create on heap, it is not read-only. I have an example for you, updated in my answer.

Comment: @KudoCC modern systems still have concept of read-only memory and `const char *` may be in read-only section of executable.

Comment: @user3125367 Of course it has, but in the case we didn't touch that.

Comment: @KudoCC The original question is about worrying, did we touch that or didn't. Just taking position is not an answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @user3125367 How can you store the large binary resource that in the question into the read-only section of executable?

Comment: iPhone definitely has read only memory -  I have myself encountered the SIGBUS signal when casting away the `const` from eg `const uint8_t array[3] = {0,1,2};`. The examples you give in your answer aren't really valid because the memory backing your `const` pointers isn't readonly - in the first instance it is on the stack, in the second it is on the heap. They are both read+write. Here is an example of the memory crash: http://ideone.com/O8d6fC

Comment: @WayneUroda Yeah, you are right. You needn't worry about it because you can't store your large binary resource into a const array struct, can you.

Comment: Yes you can and we do, which is the whole reason I am asking the question!!

Comment: Thanks for your comments about why is it void and not const void, that makes sense. I am going to assume though that it isn't safe to use NSData in this way, I'd rather be safe than have to worry about it breaking later.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: … freeWhenDone:NO] with a const byte array as input?

As long as you don't (or can't) free the storage and as long as you don't change the content of the storage, you are fine. e.g.

```
static const char* foo = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
```

is safe to use.

> I am just wondering, since dataWithBytesNoCopy: takes a void* and not const void*, does this mean it is not safe to use this from a constant source

Only if you put

```
[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: … freeWhenDone:YES]
                                            ^^^
```

The fact that it you can ask the object to free the data when it is deallocated is the only reason for the pointer being `void*` instead of `const void*`

Comment: Thanks for the input, as I commented at the top I think I will just refactor the NSData out of it altogether (after I profile to see if it is worth it)

Answer (score 0):

Below code fixes issues for converting large set of byte arrays from server.

```
    NSString* version = [socketDict objectForKey:@"version"];
    NSArray *myBytes = [socketDict objectForKey:@"newFirmware"];
    NSUInteger packageLength = myBytes.count;

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:packageLength];

    for ( NSString *myByte in myBytes) {

        int i = [myByte intValue];
        [data appendBytes:&i length:1];

    }
```